# DT gets refreshed quickly if updateselectInput() is used

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In a shiny application, the choices of the **selectInput()** are updated based on the values of the column **Grade** in the dataframe **df**. I need to display a DT table based on the unique values of Grade.

```
ui <- uiOutput('mainPage')


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  grade <- c("All",9,10,11,12)

  output$mainPage <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(

      selectInput(inputId = "grade",shiny::HTML
                  ("<span style='color: white'>Designation</span>"),
                  choices = grade),
      DTOutput('table')
    )
  })


  output$table <- renderDT({

    df <-  data.frame("Name" = c('Arun','Ram','Krishna','Rama','Ashwin'),
                      "Grade" = c(10,11,10,12,11),
                      "StressLevel" = c('Stressful','Very stressful','Very stressful','Stressful','Stressful'))

    df$Name<-as.character(df$Name)

    rownames(df) <- c()

    selectedGrade <- as.list(unique(df[,"Grade"]))

    updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "grade",
                      choices = c("All",selectedGrade))


    if(input$grade == "All"){

      dataSelected <- df[,c(1,3)]

      stressCount <- length(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel))
      if(stressCount == 2){
        color = c('#ff684c','#e03426')
      }else{
        color = c('#ff684c')
      }
      if(stressCount == 0){
        color = c()
      }



      datatable(dataSelected, options = list(pageLenth = 5, searching = FALSE,
                                             lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20),lengthChange = FALSE,
                                             scrollX = T, autoWidth = TRUE,
                                             initComplete = JS(
                                               "function(settings, json) {",
                                               "$(this.api().table().header()).css({ 
                                               'color': '#fff'});",
                                               "}")))%>% formatStyle(
                                                 'StressLevel',
                                                 Color = styleEqual(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel), 
                                                                    color))


  }else{

    dataSelected <- df %>% filter(Grade == input$grade)

    dataSelected <- dataSelected[,c(1,3)]

    stressCount <- length(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel))
    if(stressCount == 2){
      color = c('#ff684c','#e03426')
    }else{
      color = c('#ff684c')
    }

    if(stressCount == 0){
      color = c()
    }

    datatable(dataSelected, options = list(pageLenth = 5, searching = FALSE,
                                           lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20),lengthChange = FALSE,
                                           scrollX = T, autoWidth = TRUE,
                                           initComplete = JS(
                                             "function(settings, json) {",
                                             "$(this.api().table().header()).css({ 
                                             'color': '#fff'});",
                                             "}"))) %>% formatStyle(
                                               'StressLevel',
                                               Color = styleEqual(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel),color))     
}
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Initially, the datatable is displayed with the choice **All** as the value.  If I select other choices, say for instance 10, DT displays the data related to grade 10 but it gets refreshed quickly. The consequence faced is, the data for the grades other than **All** cannot be viewed.

Can anyone provide a suitable solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the `selected` argument of `updateSelectInput()` to retain the current selection:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- uiOutput('mainPage')

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  grade <- c("All", 9, 10, 11, 12)

  output$mainPage <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(selectInput(
      inputId = "grade",
      shiny::HTML
      ("<span style='color: white'>Designation</span>"),
      choices = grade
    ),
    DTOutput('table'))
  })


  output$table <- renderDT({
    DF <-
      data.frame(
        "Name" = c('Arun', 'Ram', 'Krishna', 'Rama', 'Ashwin'),
        "Grade" = c(10, 11, 10, 12, 11),
        "StressLevel" = c(
          'Stressful',
          'Very stressful',
          'Very stressful',
          'Stressful',
          'Stressful'
        )
      )

    DF$Name <- as.character(DF$Name)

    rownames(DF) <- c()

    selectedGrade <- as.list(unique(DF[, "Grade"]))

    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      inputId = "grade",
      choices = c("All", selectedGrade),
      selected = isolate({
        input$grade
      })
    )


    if (input$grade == "All") {
      dataSelected <- DF[, c(1, 3)]

      stressCount <- length(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel))
      if (stressCount == 2) {
        color = c('#ff684c', '#e03426')
      } else{
        color = c('#ff684c')
      }
      if (stressCount == 0) {
        color = c()
      }



      datatable(
        dataSelected,
        options = list(
          pageLenth = 5,
          searching = FALSE,
          lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
          lengthChange = FALSE,
          scrollX = T,
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings, json) {",
            "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
                                               'color': '#fff'});",
            "}"
          )
        )
      ) %>% formatStyle('StressLevel',
                        Color = styleEqual(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel),
                                           color))


    } else{
      dataSelected <- DF %>% filter(Grade == input$grade)

      dataSelected <- dataSelected[, c(1, 3)]

      stressCount <- length(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel))
      if (stressCount == 2) {
        color = c('#ff684c', '#e03426')
      } else{
        color = c('#ff684c')
      }

      if (stressCount == 0) {
        color = c()
      }

      datatable(
        dataSelected,
        options = list(
          pageLenth = 5,
          searching = FALSE,
          lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
          lengthChange = FALSE,
          scrollX = T,
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings, json) {",
            "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
                                             'color': '#fff'});",
            "}"
          )
        )
      ) %>% formatStyle('StressLevel',
                        Color = styleEqual(unique(dataSelected$StressLevel), color))
    }
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Furthermore, I set `server = FALSE` for `renderDT()` to prevent the flashing of the "processing..." message when the datatable is re-rendered.